# Change Background Color of iOS App When Pushing Views

Tags: ios, xcode, image, transition, pushviewcontroller

In my app, I use a navigation controller to switch between different views.  Each of my views has an image for a background, but when I go from one to another, a little bit of white shows up in between them while transitioning.  Is there a way to change that?

In the Table View Class I have this in the viewDidLoad:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"parchment.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
    [imageView release];
```

In the detail view I have just a standard loadrequest for an HTML.  The HTML itself has the code for the parchment paper to be a background image.  Here is what they look like:

[image]

[image]

But, going back from the detail view with the verses to the table view, I get this:
[image]

Comment: Did you change background color for view, tableView etc.. in that class. for table view you can use, `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor color..];`

Comment: @ACB Guys I think it's happening to the second view. Not the first view. So its not anything to do with table view background. I think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in the viewWillDisappear of the web view controller.  It was set to change webpage to about:blank page, which made it white.  I got rid of that code, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

In your:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method of AppDelegate. assign background color to window like this:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // or anycolor
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing the background color property of the view?

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect anything.  See edits to OP for pics and details.

Comment: @user717452, How about adding that in `viewWillAppear`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the background color of the navigation controller's view.

In your navigation controller's root view controller (I guess it's the table view controller)

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = // any color ;
```